# SQL Query To Count And Print Respective Matches

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have written a SQL query that looks something like this sample snippet

```
SELECT  a.account, P.account_2, P.id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN P.status = 'NOT_RUN' then 1 else NULL end) AS not_run,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN P.status = 'run' then 1 else NULL end) AS run,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN P.status = 'failed' then 1 else NULL end) AS failed
FROM table1 P 
INNER JOIN 
    table2 a ON P.id = a.uuid
GROUP BY P.account_2, P.id, a.account
```

This gives me

```
Row    account    account_2    id    not_run   run    failed
1      A1         X            C1    4         2      1
```

There is another column called `task_name` which can have `status` of `run`, `not_run`, `failed`

Now for this, there are 7 `task_name` out of which 4 are in `not_run`

I am trying to understand if there is a way I can add another column after not_run to add all the `task_name` matching that status.

Similarly, I then can add more columns to do a count of run and the tasks with that in adjacent columns and so on.

Comment: For your request you require a "group concatenation" **BUT** the syntax of this feature changes for almost every database - and you have not told us which database you use. If you hover over the tag "sql" it informs you that **"Questions should include ... a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used."**

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL**

```
SELECT a.account
    , P.account_2
    , P.id
    , COUNT( 1 ELSE NULL END) AS not_run
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN P.STATUS = 'run' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS run
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN P.STATUS = 'failed' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS failed
    , GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN P.STATUS = 'NOT_RUN' THEN P.task_name END) AS not_run_tasks
FROM table1 P
INNER JOIN table2 a ON P.id = a.uuid
GROUP BY P.account_2
    , P.id
    , a.account;
```

**Postgres** (and SQL Server 2017 and later)

```
    , STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN P.STATUS = 'NOT_RUN' THEN P.task_name END) AS not_run_tasks
```

This is why you should always include the actual dbms as the tag ("sql" by itself often does not help us much)